# Imagemagick naming from composite stack

Tags: imagemagick

How can I reuse the naming from the composite stack in here, where I want to re-use the file name image123 from the stack?

`magick composite -gravity center -geometry +0+200 \( image123.png -set filename:origin %t_op -resize '150%' -colorspace gray \) background.png '%[filename:origin]'.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using ImageMagick v7 in most cases you don't need to use the sub-command "composite". Just use "magick".

To use the input filename as the output filename you'll have to do a little tricky managing IM's built-in special variable "filename:". Near the beginning of the command, set a variable with "-set option:var" to the filename of the first input file. Then near the end of the command set the special "filename:" variable using that first variable. Try something like this...

```
magick image123.png -set option:var "%[t]" -resize "150%" \
   -colorspace gray background.png +swap -gravity center \
   -geometry +0+200 -composite -set filename:f "%[var]" "%[filename:f].jpg"
```

You may have to change some of those double quotes " to singles '.

Comment: Nice, GeeMack. I had not thought of the double -set option and -set filename.

Comment: Great! This worked out great! I loved your solution because it kept the original specification from my script.

Comment: Could you explain, why `+swap` is being used?

Comment: When doing overlays with "magick", the background image has to be first in the list because it gets placed on the canvas first. (That's opposite of how the "composite" command works.) Since the example command reads the overlay image first then the background image, the "+swap" switches places of those two images so the background will be on the bottom for the "-composite" operation.

Comment: Thanks. What does the  `%[t]` and `%[var]` do? Looks like it is assigning the value, but it is never used again.

I've noticed from some example, "%[t]" or "%t_foo" was kept being used, but I couldn't find the explanation from the document.

Comment: The "%[var]" is a user defined variable set with `-set option:var "something"`. You can use almost any name for it. The "%[t]" is a built-in IM variable that holds the filename of the (usually) first image in the list. It can be a bit tricky to use as with our example command above. You can find more about IM's percent escape variables [at this LINK](https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use magick, not magick composite. The latter does not support -set filename. Also, when doing a -compose over -composite, I do not believe that the -set filename will work directly for the overlay image, only for the background image. That is it must be the first image in the command line for magick.

However, here is workaround that reverse the order of the images so the overlay is first and then use 'dstover' rather than 'over' as the compose method.

Background Image:

[image]

Overlay Image:

[image]

```
magick \
rose.png -set filename:origin "%t_op" -resize '150%' -colorspace gray \
-background none -gravity center -extent 640x480-0-100 \
logo.png -compose dstover -composite \
'%[filename:origin].jpg'
```

[image]

**ADDITION:**

Here is a similar solution that gets the dimensions automatically.

```
magick logo.png -set option:dims "%wx%h" -write mpr:logo +delete \
rose.png -set filename:origin "%t_op" -resize '150%' -colorspace gray \
-background none -gravity center -extent "%[dims]-0-100" \
mpr:logo -compose dstover -composite \
'%[filename:origin].jpg'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It didn't produce the result I was looking for, because I don't want to set the dimension hardcoded. I want to keep it dynamic.

Comment: The dimension can be saved use -set option from the background image, if arranged properly. But GeeMack's solution is much better.

Comment: See my ADDITION for how to avoid the hard dimension in my method. However, GeeMack's solution is better.